# Error: [ngRepeat:iexp] Expected expression in form of '_item_ in _collection_[ track by _id_]' but got '\"movie'

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to test my Rails/Angular app in production Rails server and I'm getting an error in my console I don't know how to fix.

The error is,

```
Error: [ngRepeat:iexp] Expected expression in form of '_item_ in _collection_[ track by _id_]' but got '\"movie'.
```

The line of code,

```
%li.animate-repeat.search_results{"ng-if" => " movie.poster_path && movie.release_date", "ng-repeat" => "movie in movieList | orderBy:'-release_date'"}
```

The error is resolved when I remove the `| orderBy:'-release_date'` but obviously that's a filter I need.

Is there a good reason why this error is occuring?

Comment: is the html outputed correctly ? (if you view the html source)

Comment: No there's a lot of static code comming from somewhere that is placed in the code. You think that has to do with it?

Comment: that's probably be the issue then (make sure you view the source with Ctrl+U, not the chrome dev tool .. or some other dev tools)

Comment: In the end the problem of the extra code resulted in this error. The extra code came from a old sprockets gem.

Comment: Then, please post an answer and accept it (after 2 days), in order to help others in future. Thanks

Comment: Refer to these two URLS : 
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/iexp
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36544472/expected-expression-in-form-of-item-in-collection-track-by-id-but-got

Answer (score -3):

You should check very well , all ng-repeats , specially if you have more than one ng-repeat within your page, I had the same error until I scan through my code carefulyl and found the issue

I read this from [Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/iexp)