# Expected expression in form of '_item_ in _collection_[ track by _id_]' but got ''

Tags: angularjs

In my ng-repeats I get error:

> "Error: [ngRepeat:iexp] Expected expression in form of '*item* in
>   *collection*[ track by *id*]' but got ''.

Even if this error appears application is not broken and works just fine, however nobody like huge errors in their console. What might cause it? How do I fix it?

I have this ng-repeat code in my view:

```
  <div class="input-dual" ng-controller="DateCtrl">
    <div class="input-dual-inner">
      <span>Datum polaska:</span>
      <select>
        <option>-</option>
        <option ng-repeat="year in years">{{year}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-dual-inner">
      <select>
        <option>-</option>
        <option ng-repeat="month in months">{{month.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and this is the controller for it:

```
AppControllers.controller('DateCtrl', [
  '$scope','$http',
  function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('/dates').then(function(response){
      $scope.years = response.data.years
      $scope.months = []
      for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        $scope.months.push(response.data.months[i])
      }
    })
  }
]);
```

This is how JSON file looks like:

```
{"years":[2016,2017],"months":[{"no":"01","name":"Siječanj"},{"no":"02","name":"Veljača"},{"no":"03","name":"Ožujak"},{"no":"04","name":"Travanj"},{"no":"05","name":"Svibanj"},{"no":"06","name":"Lipanj"},{"no":"07","name":"Srpanj"},{"no":"08","name":"Kolovoz"},{"no":"09","name":"Rujan"},{"no":"10","name":"Listopad"},{"no":"11","name":"Studeni"},{"no":"12","name":"Prosinac"}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a `model` to both the `select` just as i added `selectedYear` and `selectedMonth`

```
<select ng-model='selectedYear' ng-options='year as year for year in years'>
</select>
<select ng-model='selectedMonth' ng-options='month as month.name for month in
months'></select>
```

and in `*.js` file or under `scripts` tag `initialize` them like (with your default value):-

```
  $scope.selectedYear = $scope.years[0];
  $scope.selectedMonth = $scope.months[0];
```

Comment: Just curious - what's the point of that first `year as year` in `year as year for year in years`?

Comment: just a `syntatic-sugar`, it could be anything, I chose the same name for simplicity (if the property if complex)

Comment: Yes, but X as X ? Why bother? Can't you just `for year in years`, or do you have to has an `X as Y`?